# Task Assignment in Sequential Order

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list

I am somewhat new to workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013.  I have a list of individuals that I want to assign task to in order.  The list of names that are to be assigned to a task I put in a choice column in SharePoint Custom list.  For each task that comes into the office I want assign the task to the next person in the list.  For example, Susan Joe was just assigned a task that came into the office.  Next person that should receive the next task is Smith Jones.  The remaining list is:

## 1 Susan Joe

## 2 Smith Jones

## 3 Bob Doe

When the list reaches the last person it starts all over again from the beginning (ex: Susan Joe). A solution I was thinking is to create a Workflow. In the workflow I will have Assign Task action and a loop that loops back to the beginning when it reaches Bob Doe.  I am sure if this is the best way to approach.  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with the assignee names and an additonal column say, 'count'.

In the main workflow, loop through the namesList and check which item has the least count and ID. Increment the count in namesList after assigning the task.

Comment: This is helpful.  What action would I use to count the increment in namesList after assigning the task?